# Efectos secundarios de crear instancias de modelos en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día,

Para crear una instancia de algún modelo en laravel, por ejemplo, del modelo `User`, haría lo siguiente:

```
$tempUser = new User();
```

Y podría utilizar todos los atributos y métodos del modelo desde `$tempUser`

Si no quisiera guardar esta instancia en mi base de datos, ¿Hay algún método para "destruir" esta instancia? Si pienso como si fuera C++ tengo un constructor, para crear instancias, y un destructor, para eliminarlas. Lo que quiero decir es, ¿Hay alguna forma de liberar la memoria de esa instancia `$tempUser` si ya no la voy a utilizar?

¿Podría hacerlo al simplemente hacer `$tempUser = null`?

¿Cuál sería el efecto secundario de crear muchas instancias del modelo `User` sin guardarlas en mi base de datos? ¿De qué forma se "libera" esa memoria?

Comment: Parece un tema más de PHP que de laravel (te sugiero agregarle esa etiqueta para que tu pregunta llegue a más usuarios). En el [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) creo que puedes encontrar la respuesta a *"¿Hay algún método para "destruir" esta instancia?"* > Sí, hay, pero no lo puedes llamar tú desde tu código, sino que *"será llamado tan pronto como no hayan otras referencias a un objeto determinado, o en cualquier otra circunstancia de finalización"*

Comment: Gracias, no estaba seguro si aplicaba el mismo concepto de PHP para los modelos de Laravel ya que no he visto que los modelos tengan el método `__destruct()` a menos que esté implícito

Comment: `__destruct()` es uno de los [métodos mágicos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php) *"que sobreescriben acciones por defecto cuando se realizan ciertas acciones sobre un objeto."*, supongo que los modelos [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php) no lo definen porque nos necesitan sobreescribirlo. Igual probablemente algún usuario con más conocimiento en PHP pueda escribir una respuesta más detallada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método mágico `__destruct` existe en todos los objetos (no sólo las instancias de clase) y no tiene mucho sentido llamarlo explícitamente, porque lo que en general elimina ese objeto de la memoria es el garbage collector.

En el ejemplo más simple, efectivamente asignar la variable a `null` la hará limpiar por parte del GC.

```
$casa = new Casa(['puertas'=>2]);

$casa->__destruct(); // no hace nada, `$casa` sigue sosteniendo la instancia

$casa = NULL ;  // ya nadie apunta a la instancia, el GC se la llevará
```

Sin embargo hay casos donde sí tiene sentido:

```
 $casa = new Casa([
  'ventanas' => new Ventana(),
  'puerta' => new Puerta()
  'escritura' => fopen('escritura.txt')
  'db_conn' => new PDO('...')
]);
```

Asignar NULL a la casa no libera sus recursos anidados. En particular, para referencias a un `resource` (en este caso un archivo abierto), éste queda tomado en el modo en que lo abriste hasta que llamas a `fclose`. Otros tienen una manera específica para ser liberados.

```
class Casa {

   public function __construct($options) 

   public function __destruct() {
       // acá nos preocupamos de liberar los recursos anidados ya sea asignando NULL, con fclose, lo que sea.
   }
}
```

En frameworks maduros como Laravel ya hay gente preocupada de que este tipo de aspectos del ciclo de vida tengan cierto control de calidad. Pero, por supuesto, a esa gente se le confió tamaño deber porque en algún momento levantaron la bandera cuando detectaron que no se limpiaba el stack al final de cada request o comando.

Queda mucho por descubrir y optimizar de Laravel. Puedes mirar por ejemplo el paquete `using` [que publicó Ryan Chandler el año pasado](https://github.com/ryangjchandler/using), el cual se vale del segmento `finally` de los bloques `try/catch` para ejecutar cierta lógica homóloga al GC pero aplicada a los descriptores de archivo abiertos.

¿Tiene sentido hacerlo? Hay que evaluar caso a caso, pero en tu caso no, no es el camino. Si acaso hoy estás procesando una cantidad grosera de instancias de un modelo que no piensas persistir, y tienes dudas acerca del impacto de ese procedimiento

1. Mide tiempo y memoria en el caso base
2. Haz tu optimización
3. Repite 1

Verás que no hay mucho espacio para optimizar por este lado. Lo que sí te permitirá optimizar y eliminar caídas por uso de memoria, es usar Jobs y no ejecutar este tipo de lógica durante un request sino cuando el scheduler esté programado.

Cuando es un proceso que ya convertiste en job y corres mediante el scheduler, entonces puedes optimizarlo pasándolo a un queue worker. Cuando esto también lo hiciste, puedes usar Batches para encolar un conjunto limitado (a tu criterio dadas las mediciones de carga) de jobs que fallarán o terminarán juntos.

Finalmente, siempre hay que considerar la posibilidad de que el proceso que estás haciendo deba replantearse radicalmente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación detallada. En mi caso tengo una sola instancia en los view donde accedo a bases de datos, pero la pregunta me vino a la mente pensando en casos donde tuviera que utilizar muchas más

Comment: Es una duda válida viniendo de un lenguaje de bajo nivel. Aunque PHP no es tan lejano hay aspectos que son más bien opacos, ya sea porque delegan en bindings nativos del sistema operativo o porque son aspectos con poco margen de optimización. Para los usuarios tan avanzados como para meter mano en ellos siempre es posible hacerlo en el código fuente de PHP. El repositorio es abierto y puedes ver el backstage escrito en C: https://github.com/php/php-src/pulls